# $Spin_n(q)$, $SO_n(q)$, $\Omega_n(q)$ and their projective images

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, groups-of-lie-type

I am studying about the structure of orthogonal groups and struggling to understand  the relations between groups in the title:

From algebraic groups point of view, it is known that $Spin_n(q)$ is the univesal cover of the simple orthogonal group $P\Omega_n(q)$, that is, $Spin_n(q)$ is the biggest perfect group such that $Spin_n(q)/Z(Spin_n(q)) \cong P\Omega_n(q)$ (*).

Moreover, by the short exact sequence $1 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow Spin_n(q) \rightarrow SO_n(q) \rightarrow 1 $, we have $Spin_n(q)/\mathbb{Z}_2 \cong SO_n(q)$ (**).

This is while $SO_n(q)$ is not generally a perfect group and it has a subgroup of index 2, which is its derived subgroup $\Omega_n(q)$. Even more, the projective image of $SO_n(q)$ by its center is not generally a simple group. Therefore, using  (**), we deduce that

$(Spin_n(q)/\mathbb{Z}_2) / (Z(Spin_n(q))/\mathbb{Z}_2) \cong SO_n(q)/Z(SO_n(q))=PSO_n(q)$,

which is not generally simple. This seems to be in contradiction with (*).

Now my question is that how can we explain (*) and (**) together, for example in cases when $n$ is odd.

Comment: How can $Spin(q)$ be perfect, and $SO(q)$ (a quotient) not be?

Comment: @Hempelicious This is exactly what I am confusing about.

Comment: @Hempelicious Except a few cases, it is known that the universal covers of simple orthogonal groups are precisely the corresponding simply-connected algebraic group over the finite field. So here the universal cover must be Spin group which has SO as a quotient, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group

Comment: But $P\Omega_5(3)$ has order $25920$, while $SO_5(3)$ has order twice that. Since the universal cover of $P\Omega_5(3)$ is 2-sheeted, how can both coverings be the same group? The orders don't match.

Comment: According to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra#Spinor_norm), the map you have in (**) is not surjective when $q$ is odd.